# Superuser gets created in the database but I can't login in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    # Manager class for users

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        # Method for creating user
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):  # autoslugfield
        """Create and return a new superuser."""
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


# Custom User Model for the system
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    "Users in the system"
    uid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = AutoSlugField(unique=True, populate_from="name")

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

When I create a django superuser, a user gets created with value `1` in the fields `is_superuser`, `is_active` and `is_staff`. But when I try to login in the django admin with the credentials, this following error occurs saying:

> "Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

I have tried several approaches but nothing works.

The following link is the screenshot:

[image: Can't Login to Django Admin after creating superuser]

Answer (score 0):

If the main goal is to simply change a few fields and set the **"username as the email"**, I found that simply overriding the save method to do so was less troublesome than trying to override the user config + the user manager + the django commands.

Basically:

- Email becomes mandadory
- On user save, you set username as email

As a result, you dont have to break/override anything since you are still using the username. But your username is the same as the email.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)


    def save(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        if self.username != self.email:
            self.username = self.email
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If that fits your need, I think it will also fix your issue with the superuser not being created correctly

Comment: In my model, there is no field named 'username'. So this save method is showing an error - "AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'username'"

I am using email for login credential. --> USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

Comment: and I am using AbstractBaseUser not AbstractUser as per my company instruction.

Comment: Alright if you cannot inherit from `AbstractUser` it will indeed not work. Do you have access to the DB to see what's in it, and more specifically the line of the superuser that was supposedly created?

Comment: Yes, I have access. is_staff, is_superuser, and is_active all are True (1) there. The password is hashed.

Answer (score 0):

To create a superuser in Django, you need to ensure that the `is_staff`
attribute is set to True for that user. In your code, you have the create_superuser method, but you are not explicitly setting the is_staff attribute to True. Here's how you can correct your code:

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

```
    """Create and return a new superuser."""
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)  # Set is_staff to True
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)  # Set is_superuser to True

    user = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
    user.save(using=self._db)

    return user
```

Make sure to update your database with this change (run migrations) after making the code modification.